# How i can create License Management Org (LMO). I am Parnter Portal member. i submitted many cases for it

Tags: appexchange

I am a partner portal member i want to upload a a package to appExchange but i don't kow how to create LMO Org and also also to get LMA for that. I submitted many cases for all these but get no idea and response.

Comment: Have you requested CRM for ISV organization org ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a salesforce partner first.

Once you are a partner you will have the LMO org on which LMA is just a package from appexchange that you need to install.

Refer to this link for more details - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you are a Partner you can submit a case in the Partner Portal which it sounds like you have already done. You will need to make sure your app has passed the security review which you can also do in the Partner Portal. Is your app free or paid? My App is free and this is the response I received once I submitted a case:

> Free app partners are eligible for the LMA and their 2 free CRM
>   licenses once they create a listing for their application on the
>   Appexchange, set the pricing to free, and accept our terms &
>   conditions.

Once I had met this criteria they set up an org with the required apps installed.
Note, they have recently changed the Partner Portal to make the process easier, in fact it is no longer the Partner Portal but the Partner Community entirely where these used to be two separate things.
I hope that helps!

Comment: binaryLdy its solved my problem